# Objective-c: How to display html <img> tags as images in iOS without UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, json

I'm developing an iOS application for a news website, the application gets its JSON data from a url, the data is an HTML and sometimes has images embedded in them like this:

```
<div class="row ">some text here then <div class="col-xs-12 ">
<div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 pull-right">
<img src="image_url" /></div></div>
```

By far i know how to get only text (remove all html tags) but i don't know how to display the images that are embedded in that string.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

**Note** i researched a lot and didn't find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just like a web browser, you would need to make a separate HTTP request for the image data. It seems that if you're getting HTML data to display, why wouldn't you use a UIWebView?

Comment: a UIWebview is not native, i need a full native ios app, plus it's laggy on older iphones

Comment: Good luck then. Writing an HTML renderer is hard.

Comment: i did that in android (java) but i suppose it's hard to do that in objective-c ?

Comment: [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UIImageView+AFNetworking category. There is a method [`- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.3/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/setImageWithURL:) that will allow you set the image property on UIImageView with a url and asynchronous network call.

Comment: again, not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png"];//This is Example url you can write your URL.

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

[self.imageview1 setImage:image];
```

Comment: This code if for a single image that you already know the url for it, this is not what i want.

Comment: @ANA what you want exactly. please tell me.

Comment: @ANA for multiple images you just want to use for loop and store all image url into one NSMutableArray.

Comment: no, what i want is: i have a string and this string includes text and images all wrapped up inside html tags like div span and <img> tags for images, i want to display text but also the images as well.

Comment: You can get this images.. by using key image_url

Answer (score 0):

Beside try

```
self.imageview1 = [UIImage  dataWithContentsOfURL@"http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png"];
```